# Avoiding nested for loops in 2D game engine

Tags: algorithm, loops, game-engine

I am creating a 2D game.

There are many `objects`, each has a width, a height, and X and Y coordinates.

Each object is stored in an `array` of it's class:

- the player
- allies
- enemies
- obstacles
- power ups
- bullets shot by the enemies
- bullets shot by the player & allies

To make the game work, I need to obviously detect if two elements occupy the same space (let's call it "collission") , so that

- the player can collect power ups
- nobody can pass through obstacles
- the allies can shoot the enemies
- the enemies can shoot the allies
- friendly fire can be either enabled or disabled

this needs to be checked every frame, 60 times per second.

What I have been doing so far, is loop through each class, and then loop over each class that it can interact with.

For example:

```
foreach (ally_bullets)
{
    foreach (enemies)
    {
        if ( collision detected between enemy and bullet )
        {
            remove the bullet and the enemy
        }
    }
}
```

It makes sense and it works, but it's very resource intensive as the game gets more complex. The more elements there are, the longer this nested for loop takes to render, ultimately reducing the frame rate. Even if I am trying to run as few loops as possible.

**What's a better way of solving this then nested for loops?**

Comment: Currently the time complexity is `O(BN)` where `B` is the number of bullets and `N` the number of characters. You can reduce this down to an average case of `O(B log N)` using a spatial subdivision data structure such as a quadtree.

Comment: Have you considered looking at  tutorials about collision detection in 2d games? Maybe interesting? https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/2d-platform-games-collision-detection-for-dummies/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution is to use [Polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/), in which you have a base class (in this case Object) which gets inherited by other classes (such as Player, Bullet, Enemy, etc). Instead of each of these having an individual array, you would have a single array (or typically more appropriate, a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)). Now you just loop through that one array having each Object do their updates, and have their updates checked against every Object in the array.

This 'vector-wise' updating is usually setup as a [Messaging System](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-implement-and-use-a-message-queue-in-your-game--cms-25407). Now whenever an inherited Object receives a message (such as 'hit by bullet'), that object checks if it cares about that message. If so, accept the message, else ignore it.

This is (in my opinion) the better way to handle what you are trying to accomplish, which I believe is what you were asking.

If you are still using arrays for this, I am going to assume you are still fairly new to programming, and I am going to suggest sticking with what you have now. It will absolutely work (providing you know how to finish your project), and when you finish this and start to learn something more advanced you will see both the shortcomings of the way you are doing it, and the benefits of it).

If you do see some lag arise, it will likely be from your drawing methods long before this kind of interactivity checking becomes a bottleneck.

Either way you go, collision detection itself and rendering are going to be the main areas your cpu will be eaten up, providing your arrays stay within reasonable ranges.

Edit:
    Another thing that will help you should you pursue the topics I mentioned is the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), also known as the [Listener Pattern](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/197421-the-listener-pattern/).

Comment: Thank you for reference to all the advanced concepts and design patterns, I can definitely see them being useful!
To summarize: you suggest to just make one array containing every object, and looping over it in one sweep. 
Overall this doesn't avoid a nested loop, but it reduces it to only one. And you imply that doing so shouldn't cause a bottle neck, and the lag problem likely occurs elsewhere.
Thank you! :-)

Comment: Seems like that is a good summary, yes.
This would be a good-deal more advanced of an approach, but this is the common way I have seen it handled.

As for it being a bottleneck, it will all depend on your coding. ^^